# MYSQL datadir renames itself after rebooting server

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat

I've mounted MySQL datadir to separate disk due to space constraint in the Redhat server. The problem occurs whenever I rebooted my Server. After the reboot, the existing MySQL datadir i.e., `Mysqldata` for example is renamed to `Mysqldata_` and new `Mysqldata` directory is created which in turn creates new instance of MySQL.

So everytime whenever I reboot, I've to change the MySQL datadir to newly renamed one in MySQL configuration file. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

I want to stop the server from renaming correct datadir. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the /etc/init.d/mysqld script and mysql_install_db found that the datadir does not exist or empty they will try to create it if they has the right permissions.
If you started your mysql server before your separate disk been mounted, the datadir may be empty, and the /etc/init.d/mysqld script assuming that is a brand new environment, so it will run mysql_install_db to create default database, that's may be the reason you get a new instance of MySQL.
But they will not cp or mv directory.
You may have other scripts to handle the rename action. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Xcat. Is there any way to check if the disks are mounted before running mysql_install_db ? Or is there any way to find the script that is responsible for renaming and moving datadir ?

Comment: How do you mount the separate disk? Did you add the datadir mount point into /etc/fstab? You can try to check /etc/rc.local or /etc/rc.d/rc3.d <- depends on your run level to find out if there are any scripts